# Displaying value from context.xml in html

Tags: java

I have a variable in server context.xml

```
<Environment name="URL" value="test.com" type="java.lang.string">
```

Is there any way we can display the value from conext in html directly without controller? Any suggestions on this is so much appreciated.

If it was JSP it is possible to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML pages you can not access to contents on server, except downloadable files that located at web directory. HTML's does not rendered on server and you need some rendering action to access context.xml values.